# SEHException occurred

Tags: c#, windows

All of a sudden **SEHException** occurred while trying access the assembly thorugh network. Application has been deployed in server (`Windows server 2003`) and running in `.NET Framework 1.1` and windows `C#` application.Its been deployed and running well for quite long time.Below is the stack trace of the exception

> *'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred and was caught. 
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  06/13/2013 12:41:19  Type :
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException    mscorlib
>   Version=2.0.0.0    Culture=neutral     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 
>   Message : **External component has thrown an exception**.  Source :
>   mscorlib  Help link :   ErrorCode : **-2147467259**  Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  Stack Trace :    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetResource(String resourceName    UInt64&
>   length     StackCrawlMark& stackMark   Boolean skipSecurityCheck)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetResource(String resourceName     UInt64&
>   length     StackCrawlMark& stackMark   Boolean skipSecurityCheck)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String name
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark  Boolean skipSecurityCheck)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Type type     String
>   name   Boolean skipSecurityCheck   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   culture    Boolean createIfNotExists   Boolean tryParents)     at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   culture    Boolean createIfNotExists   Boolean tryParents)     at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   culture    Boolean createIfNotExists   Boolean tryParents)     at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name     CultureInfo
>   culture    Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)     at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)    at
>   shoppingcartBO.messageLabel_Paint(Object sender    PaintEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e
>   Int16 layer    Boolean disposeEventArgs)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd
>   Int32 msg  IntPtr wparam   IntPtr lparam)*

The issue did not occur after closing and relaunching the application. We are getting this issue reported almost over 200  times now, and we need to solve it.

Comment: What is your code that is causing this error or that you suspect causing the issue?

Comment: It might not be a code issue, because the code is running well for quite sometime in production. All of a sudden this issue occurred.

Answer (score 1):

In our case this problem was caused by following:

1. Application was launched from network share from remote computer
2. Client computer was put to sleep with application running
3. Application on network share was updated to new exe file
4. Cient computer was resumed. Application was still running with old (cached in memory) version of the exe. After that, some action in application initiated the call of `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` which resulted in `SEHException`

We fixed this with reorganizing the application so that this situation does not occur.